# Java- A class has an annotation, how to test this class without that annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations

Eaxmple:

```
1 @Schema // you don't need to care what Schema annotation is
2 public class A {
3     public Schema getSchema() {
4         Schema schema = getClass().getAnnotation(Schema.class);
5         if (schema == null) {
6             throw new IllegalStateException("Schema annotation is missing for class " + getClass().getName());
7         }
8         return schema;
9     }
10 }
```

How can I write a unit test that can cover line 6.
Now I can only cover line 4,5,8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario would only make sense if there are subclasses extending `class A`. So to test it, you can create a subclass and test it.

```java
@Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
public void getSchema() {
    A testClass = new A() {};
    testClass.getSchema();
}
```

Comment: And even then, this will only work if `@Schema` is not meta-annotated with `@Inherited`.

Comment: That's perfect.  I successfully cover that line. Thank you.